# React render modal in list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of items and for each item in the list has an edit button to show a modal with that items details. Originally I had a single modal component in the parent and when I click the edit button it would pass the visible values up to the parent state to show the modal.

The problem is when I did that, the entire list would re render which I dont want because the list can have hundreds of items in it. So right now the solution I have is that in each item of the list I have a modal associated with it. It works but it doesnt seem right because I am duplicated code unnecessarily.

The code is too large to put on here but these are the relevant parts:

```
import Modal from '../Modal';

const CustomCard = ({
  ...omitted
}) => {
  const [editCustomerModal, setEditCustomerModal] = useState(false);



  const onEditModal = () => {
    setEditCustomerModal(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <CustomerModal
        onSuccess={handleUpdateCustomer}
        onCancel={handleCancelModal}
        visible={editCustomerModal}
        title="Edit Customer"
        details={{
          .. ommitted
        }}
      />
      <Card />
         ....data
      </Card>
    </>
  );
};

export default CustomCard;
```

- 

```
import CustomCard from '../CustomerCard/index';



const CustomList = ({ dataSource }) => {
  
  return (
    <div>
      {dataSource?.map(i => (
        <CustomCard
          ...props ommitted
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CustomerList;
```

- ```
     import CustomerList from './components/CustomerList/index';

     // import Modal from './components/AddCustomerModal';


     const CustomersPage = () => {
       const [editCustomerModal, setEditCustomerModal] = useState(false);

       const [editCustomer, setEditCustomer] = useState(null);


   return (
     <>

       // This is where I would want it ideally
       <Modal
         onSuccess={handleSaveCustomerEdit}
         onCancel={handleCancelCustomerEdit}
         visible={editCustomerModal}
         details={editCustomer}
       />
         <CustomerList
           dataSource={data}

         />
       </div>
       {/* </ModalContext.Provider> */}
     </>
   );
  ```

  };

  export default CustomersPage;

Answer (score 0):

You can define one selected useState atribute, that stores only the register that you want to pass to your modal.

For example:

```
import CustomerList from './components/CustomerList/index';

import Modal from './components/AddCustomerModal';

const CustomersPage = () => {
    const [editCustomerModal, setEditCustomerModal] = useState(false);
    const [editCustomer, setEditCustomer] = useState(null);
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);

    return (
        <>
            <Modal
                onSuccess={handleSaveCustomerEdit}
                onCancel={handleCancelCustomerEdit}
                visible={editCustomerModal}
                details={editCustomer}
                selectedCard={selected}
            />
            
            {dataSource?.map(i => (
                <CustomCard ...props ommitted setSelected={setSelected}/>
                //somewere in CustomCard, trigger the event to set selected props that you want to pass for Modal
                //remember to be careful with nullable object. use selectedCard?.something
            ))}
        </>
    );
};

export default CustomersPage;
```

Comment: But the entire list would re render again right? Im trying to avoid rendering each element of the list

Comment: If you want to show the elements, you had to render at least one time each element of the list. But in the exemple, i render the modal just once.

Comment: Every time the modal state changes, the list re renders which is what I am trying to avoid. I want the modal as a single component as it is but I dont want to re render the list every time the modal is shown